# dbus: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.login1': timed out

Tags: linux, debian, d-bus, proftpd

I keep getting the following error messages in the syslog of one of my servers:

```
# tail /var/log/syslog
Oct 29 13:48:40 myserver dbus[19617]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.login1': timed out
Oct 29 13:48:40 myserver dbus[19617]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.login1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.login1.service'
Oct 29 13:49:05 myserver dbus[19617]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.login1': timed out
Oct 29 13:49:05 myserver dbus[19617]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.login1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.login1.service'
```

They seem to correlate to FTP Logins on the ProFTPd daemon:

```
# tail /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log
2015-10-29 13:48:40,433 myserver proftpd[17872] myserver.example.com (remote.example.com[192.168.22.33]): USER switch: Login successful.
2015-10-29 13:48:40,460 myserver proftpd[17872] myserver.example.com (remote.example.com[192.168.22.33]): FTP session closed.
2015-10-29 13:48:40,664 myserver proftpd[17881] myserver.example.com (remote.example.com[192.168.22.33]): FTP session opened.
2015-10-29 13:49:05,687 myserver proftpd[17881] myserver.example.com (remote.example.com[192.168.22.33]): USER switch: Login successful.
2015-10-29 13:49:05,705 myserver proftpd[17881] myserver.example.com (remote.example.com[192.168.22.33]): FTP session closed.
2015-10-29 13:49:05,908 myserver proftpd[17915] myserver.example.com (remote.example.com[192.168.22.33]): FTP session opened.
```

The FTP logins themselves seem to work without problems for the user, though. I've got a couple of other servers also running ProFTPd but so far never got these errors.

They might be related to a recent upgrade from Debian 7 to Debian 8 though.

Any ideas what the message want to tell me or even what causes them?

I already tried restarting the dbus and proftpd daemons and even the server and made sure that the DBUS socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket is existing but so far the messages keep coming.

EDIT:
The output of journalctl as requested in the comment:

```
root@myserver:/home/chammers# systemctl status -l dbus-org.freedesktop.login1.service
● systemd-logind.service - Login Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service; static)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2015-10-27 13:23:32 CET; 1 weeks 0 days ago
     Docs: man:systemd-logind.service(8)
           man:logind.conf(5)
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat
 Main PID: 467 (systemd-logind)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-logind.service
           └─467 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind

Oct 28 10:15:25 myserver systemd-logind[467]: New session c3308 of user switch.
Oct 28 10:15:25 myserver systemd-logind[467]: Removed session c3308.
Oct 28 10:15:25 myserver systemd-logind[467]: New session c3309 of user switch.
Oct 28 10:15:25 myserver systemd-logind[467]: Removed session c3309.
Oct 28 10:15:25 myserver systemd-logind[467]: New session c3310 of user switch.
Oct 28 10:15:25 myserver systemd-logind[467]: Removed session c3310.
Oct 28 10:15:25 myserver systemd-logind[467]: New session c3311 of user switch.
Oct 28 10:15:25 myserver systemd-logind[467]: Removed session c3311.
Oct 28 10:19:52 myserver systemd-logind[467]: New session 909 of user chammers.
Oct 28 10:27:11 myserver systemd-logind[467]: Failed to abandon session scope: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

And more journalctl output:

```
Nov 03 16:21:19 myserver dbus[19617]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.login1': timed out
Nov 03 16:21:19 myserver proftpd[23417]: pam_systemd(proftpd:session): Failed to create session: Activation of org.freedesktop.login1 timed out
Nov 03 16:21:19 myserver proftpd[23418]: pam_systemd(proftpd:session): Failed to create session: Activation of org.freedesktop.login1 timed out
Nov 03 16:21:19 myserver proftpd[23417]: pam_unix(proftpd:session): session closed for user switch
Nov 03 16:21:19 myserver proftpd[23418]: pam_unix(proftpd:session): session closed for user switch
Nov 03 16:21:19 myserver proftpd[23420]: pam_unix(proftpd:session): session opened for user switch by (uid=0)
Nov 03 16:21:19 myserver dbus[19617]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.login1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.login1.service'
Nov 03 16:21:19 myserver proftpd[23421]: pam_unix(proftpd:session): session opened for user switch by (uid=0)
```

Comment: What does `systemctl status -l dbus-org.freedesktop.login1.service` report when run as root? Does anything stand out in the output of `journalctl` (especially around the times of the error messages)?

Comment: I've added the output of systemctl/journalctl above.

Comment: Does restarting logind (`systemctl restart systemd-logind`) help?

Comment: So far it did help for the day. I've now rebooted the server to see if the problem comes back as a simple reboot never helped before I reported the problem here.

Comment: The restart seems to have fixed the problem. Almost disappointing ;) What did it do that a simple "shutdown -r now" couldn't fix? Thanks for you help!

Comment: A reboot should have fixed the problem as well. Maybe you restarted dbus after the reboot, thus reintroduced the problem.

Comment: The symptom I found were that SSH logins now took 15 seconds after entering the pass, instead of being available immediatly. Restarting systemd-logind fixed that.

Comment: See also https://serverfault.com/q/707377/89813

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Restart logind:

```
# systemctl restart systemd-logind
```

Beware that restarting dbus will break their connection again.

Comment: This solves the problem only temporarily. After a while (months) the same problem reappears.

Comment: # systemctl restart systemd-logind
Failed to restart systemd-logind.service: Connection timed out
See system logs and 'systemctl status systemd-logind.service' for details.

Comment: And did you see them, @DaliborFilus?

Comment: `≤systemctl status php7.0-fpm` did tell me the same thing, so I figured running systemctl status is pointless at that time. This was a production server, I had to act quickly. Will try next time.

Comment: Fixed it here, where the real pain point was really slow SSH login.
In my case, the issue might be related to a recent systemd update, and no reboot thereafter.
`needs-restarting` (still) says systemd needs a reboot.

Comment: This restart hung for me ...

Comment: For `systemd`-negative systems, the name of the `logind` service may be different. For instance, for [_Devuan_](https://www.devuan.org) Linux, `service elogind restart` will do the trick.

Comment: I actually had to restart both services `systemd-logind` and `dbus` to get rid of the delay.

Answer (score 8):

Reboot was the only solution that worked for me. I killed the runaway dbus process and other things failed.

This is what happened when i tried to reload httpd-

```
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Activation of org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 timed out (g-dbus-error-quark, 20)
Failed to reload httpd.service: Connection timed out
```

Centos7 is buggy.

Answer (score 3):

Restarting only systemd-logind service is not enough, it just postpones the main problem.

Seems like this is caused by too many files pilled up under '/run/systemd/system/', created by the service and not properly cleaned up, especially on hosts with a lot of logins. Eventually after some time you would start seeing some weird behavior like hostnamectl not reporting a thing, or timedatectl reports Failed to query server: Connection timed out and other odd things. As well the symptoms reported originally.

One workaround is to delete all 'session-*.scope' files and to restart systemd. Restarting the host is not necessary in that case.
  This probably is related to a bug in systemd and dbus, hopefully in next updates they will be fixed.

Comment: Any idea what is "too many"? We're having this issue on RHEL 7.8 with only 511 files under /run/systemd/system.

Answer (score 3):

On my DietPi instance, I got this filling up the log files when I enabled the serial console. The problem was that `systemd-logind.service` was masked. This was an easy fix:

```
sudo systemctl unmask systemd-logind.service
sudo systemctl start systemd-logind.service
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue when setting up a LXC container on Proxmox. The problem was caused by me not ticking the box to allowed nested containers when configuring the LXC container. As I understand it systemd-logind puts users in a container which was failing because I hadn't passed on that capability to the new machine.

Comment: Following are the lines I added to the LXC configuration for the VM (`vi /etc/pve/lxc/VMID.conf`):
```lxc.apparmor.profile: unconfined\n
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow: a\n
lxc.cap.drop: 
```

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with the same issue today and i found out that it was initially caused by a service eating up all available memory.
I found the related log lines, which made clear that it is caused by memory allocation in the */var/log/messages* log.

```
systemd: Starting Session 750154 of user root.
systemd: Failed to fork: Cannot allocate memory
systemd: Assertion 'pid >= 1' failed at src/core/unit.c:1997, function unit_watch_pid(). Aborting.
systemd: Caught <ABRT>, cannot fork for core dump: Cannot allocate memory
systemd: Freezing execution.
dbus[697]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out
```

To find out the service using most of the memory I executed this:

```
ps aux --sort=-%mem
```

To solve the issue i first tried to free the memory, but still systemd-logind was not able to start up.
Therefore I had to reboot the server and the issue was solved.

Answer (score 1):

On systems honoring init freedom like Devuan GNU+Linux (chimaera), if you do not use a GUI at all, you can purge elogind:

```
sudo apt purge elogind
```

This will install a handful new packages and purge some others, but please make sure you do not purge half of your system. It should look like:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  elogind* libpam-elogind* libpolkit-gobject-elogind-1-0* policykit-1* policykit-1-gnome*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  hdparm libpolkit-gobject-consolekit-1-0 pm-utils vbetool
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

If you are in doubt, do not proceed!

Then purge automatically installed packages, that are no longer in use:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

This will remove libpolkit-agent-1-0 or similar.

The procedure above solved the *"Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.login1': timed out"* error for me.

Answer (score -4):

Just reinstall systemd.

```
apt install --reinstall systemd
```

this resolve the issue for me on many VMs